# SQL Server : locks and exclusive type of select

Tags: sql, sql-server, multithreading, locking

Let's say we have a table `Users` with just 3 columns.

```
UserId - primary key clustered int
Username - nvarchar(50)
CityId - int, which has a non-unique non-clustered index ( mouthful ).
```

If I do a select and with an exclusive lock and a begin tran in one tab:

```
declare @CityId int = 10

begin tran
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].Users WITH (XLOCK,INDEX (MyCityIndex))  
    WHERE CityId = @CityId
```

And notice I don't commit or rollback the transaction.

Then in another ( YES ANOTHER TAB ELSE SQL WILL DO SOME OPTIMIZATION AND WONT WORK ) tab, I run:

```
declare @CityId int = 10

begin tran
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].Users WITH (XLOCK, INDEX (MyCityIndex))  
    WHERE CityId = @CityId
```

It will obviously block if I use the same `CityId` (10). But I guess what happens if I use a `CityId = 11`?

```
declare @CityId int = 11
```

It will work.

But it will work if I do a index hint search, otherwise it won't work and even if I put `CityId = 11`, then it will block and wait for other tran it will fail.

What is going on here?

When it reads data using the exclusive lock, doing a full table scan, and then once it hits a record that it is locked, is blocked? Really?

What would happen if indexes get fragmented and it hits a row that actually is blocked which does not contain its 'id'. Would that block also?

When doing the testing please use 2 different tabs for the selects because there is a SQL Server optimization here.

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/louis_davidson/archive/2006/12/13/does-xlock-always-prevent-reads-by-others.aspx

I am using SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

Different behavior suggests different execution plans. If many users have the same city, SQL Server may choose a clustered index scan because it's more efficient since you are selecting all columns. The scan will be blocked when the scan encounters an incompatible lock on a row by another session.

I think you can avoid the hint if you explicitly `INCLUDE` the other 2 columns in the MyCityIndex definition.  Alternatively, add the other 3 columns to the MyCityIndex key list after CityId.

The example below seeks using the MyCityIndex and not block even without the hint because it touches only the requested CityId values. If you remove the `INCLUDE` clause, a clustered index scan is done and the second query will be blocked.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Users(
      CityId int
    , UserID int
        CONSTRAINT PK_Users PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , OtherData int
    );
CREATE INDEX MyCityIndex ON dbo.Users(CityId) INCLUDE(UserID, OtherData);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Users VALUES(1,1,1);
INSERT INTO dbo.Users VALUES(1,2,1);
INSERT INTO dbo.Users VALUES(1,3,1);
INSERT INTO dbo.Users VALUES(10,4,1);
INSERT INTO dbo.Users VALUES(10,5,1);
INSERT INTO dbo.Users VALUES(10,6,1);
INSERT INTO dbo.Users VALUES(11,7,1);
INSERT INTO dbo.Users VALUES(11,8,1);
INSERT INTO dbo.Users VALUES(11,9,1);
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.Users;
GO

--run this on session 1
DECLARE @CityId int = 10;
BEGIN TRAN
      --SELECT * FROM dbo.Users with (XLOCK,INDEX (MyCityIndex))  where CityId= @CityId 
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Users with (XLOCK) WHERE CityId= @CityId;
--ROLLBACK;
GO

--run this on session 2
DECLARE @CityId int = 11;
BEGIN TRAN
      --SELECT * FROM dbo.Users with (XLOCK,INDEX (MyCityIndex))  where CityId= @CityId 
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Users with (XLOCK) WHERE CityId= @CityId;
--ROLLBACK;
GO
```

Comment: ty for the answer but you still have no answered my question.Does actually hitting a lock record while doing the 'select ... where .. ' statement, block? What if an index is fragmented and it contains data that should not be there.Would my solution still work?

Comment: @Aflred, I added a script to my answer that shows the query will not be blocked with a seek even without the index hint. Fragmentation does not cause index pages to contain data it shouldn't; it may reduce page life expectancy and cause more IO.

Comment: that is the exact behavior i am getting and it is correct and ty for actually trying it out yourself.Yes you have answered my entire question with the ' Fragmentation does not cause index pages to contain data it shouldn't; it may reduce page life expectancy and cause more IO', so thats that.I was wrong about indexes.'.I am guessing it all depends on the sql optimization plan.